# Removing an object from array of objects swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm trying to remove an object from array of objects

I tried different scenarios, but instead of removing item it has been added 2 times to the array, I'm going out of my mind and couldn't find any reason for that

```
 let pages = surveyData.pagerItems; // Pages is a model which contains an array of another model called question
 let questions = self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems.filter{$0.id != questionId};
 self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems = questions;
```

I tried to remove all questions items first also before assigning it to pages object

```
self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems.removeAll();
self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems = questions;
```

also tried this

```
self.pages[sourceIndex.section].questionItems.remove(at: sourceIndex.row)
```

Also when I try to insert object, it adds more than once.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Use below code, I hope it may work:-**

```
self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems.append(questions)
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. 
I added print after  removeAll        print("count\(self.pages[indexPath.section].questionItems.count)");
count is still the same

Comment: First check which section of array you want to remove, then print the output

Comment: in all cases old array doen't change it always append to it even if I remove all objects or removeAt index. I don't know why.

Comment: This is TwoD array, and above code is working for me and according to your given question. You should go through the code.

Answer (score 0):

**To remove an object from array:**

```
var array = ["First Object", "Second Object", "Third Object"]

if let index = array.index(of:"Third Object") 
{
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work too, I tried almost everything. I don't know if it has something to do with send by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your scenario, its working fine. I created a Modal named page having array variable as questions. And fill values as given below.

```
class Page {
    var questions = [String]();
}
```

Getting sample values filled.

```
    let page1 = Page();
    page1.questions.append("P1->First Element");
    page1.questions.append("P1->Second Element");
    page1.questions.append("P1->Third Element");
    page1.questions.append("P1->Fourth Element");
    page1.questions.append("P1->Fifth Element");

    let page2 = Page();
    page2.questions.append("P2->First Element");
    page2.questions.append("P2->Second Element");
    page2.questions.append("P2->Third Element");
    page2.questions.append("P2->Fourth Element");

    let page3 =  Page();
    page3.questions.append("P3->First Element");
    page3.questions.append("P3->Second Element");
    page3.questions.append("P3->Thirs Element");


    var pages = [Page]();        
    pages.append(page1);
    pages.append(page2);
    pages.append(page3);
```

Now we will see output before removing item and after removing item.

```
    print("p1.question \(pages[0].questions)");
    print("p2.question \(pages[1].questions)");
    print("p3.question \(pages[2].questions)");

    pages[1].questions.remove(at: 2);

    print("p1.question \(pages[0].questions)");
    print("p2.question \(pages[1].questions)");
    print("p3.question \(pages[2].questions)");
```

Now you can see output as expected.

```
p1.question ["P1->First Element", "P1->Second Element", "P1->Third Element", "P1->Fourth Element", "P1->Fifth Element"]
p2.question ["P2->First Element", "P2->Second Element", "P2->Third Element", "P2->Fourth Element"]
p3.question ["P3->First Element", "P3->Second Element", "P3->Thirs Element"]

p1.question ["P1->First Element", "P1->Second Element", "P1->Third Element", "P1->Fourth Element", "P1->Fifth Element"]
p2.question ["P2->First Element", "P2->Second Element", "P2->Fourth Element"]
p3.question ["P3->First Element", "P3->Second Element", "P3->Thirs Element"]
```

As you can see third Item from page at index 1 has been removed successfully.
**I think you are confusing between `let` and `var`. In swift let is immutable object where as var is mutable one.**

Comment: Thanks all, I had to do the removing, inserting, appending in the model itself.